# Circular dependency issues with inherited classes

Tags: c++, c++14

```
//grid.h
class Grid {
    ...
    std::vector<std::vector<Tile>> theBoard;
    ..
}
```

```
//tile.h
class Tile {
    ...
    Piece *piece;
    ...
}
```

```
//piece.h
class Piece {
    ...
    Grid *theBoard;
    ...
}
```

```
//queen.h
class Queen : public Piece {
    ...
}
```

We're running into linking dependency issues when we try to compile this. How do we write the include headers/forward declarations to support this?

Comment: If it compiles but doesn't link then your source code is fine. You'll need to fix the linking command in your makefile / build script.

Comment: Why is `queen.h` in this grouping? No other files reference `Queen`.

Comment: Hmm... I don't see why there would be an issue with forward declarations. What have you tried? What was the error for that try?

Comment: It'd be nice if you include the linking error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Piece.h`, you can **forward declare** the Grid-class. Forward declaration means, that you tell the computer, that a particular type exists, but it doesn't know anything about its size or members yet. You can't forward declare in `Queen.h`, since you're not allowed to inherit from a forward declared class. Furthermore, you aren't allowed to store a forward declarated class as a member, you can only store a pointer or reference to them.

```
//piece.h
// forward declaration of Grid
class Grid;

class Piece {
    ...
    Grid *theBoard;
    ...
}
```

Please note that in the implementation file of `piece.h`, you need to include `grid.h` so that the compiler can know which methods can be called on `Grid`, but since this `#include` is in the implementation file, you won't get a circular dependency.

Comment: This solved my issue, tyvm! I was aware of forward declarations but didn't know where to put one / where to use an includes

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer solved your issue, I would be grateful if you could mark my answer as the accepted one ;)

Answer (score 1):

Typically when you have circular dependencies it means you need to rethink your structure. In your case perhaps that "does a piece really need to know about the board?".

The other solution is to forward declare a class. You would do this by writing :

```
class a;
```

And this simply tells the compiler "hey, a exists, it's coming later". This can become messy very quick so it's likely better to try and rethink your structure so that your classes are more self contained and don't depend on each other as much.